# Find out the particular object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data like

```
const data = {
  Name : "Apple",
  Weight : 5,
  Address : "Somewhere",
  Contact : 777666,
  X : 908,
  Y : 562,
}
```

and another array of data as

```
const arrData = ["Name","Weight"];
```

Now I need a new data of object in a variable that has key equal to array of data.
For example required data is

```
newData = [
  {Name : "Apple"},
  {Weight: "5"},
]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Hint: you need to loop over `arrData` and set each property of an object. You can use `reduce` or a simple loop for that.

Comment: `console.log(["Name","Weight"].reduce((a,b)=>(data[b]&&(a[b]=data[b]),a),{}))`

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this?

```js
const data = { Name : "Apple", Weight : 5, Address : "Somewhere", Contact : 777666, X : 908, Y : 562, }

const arrData = ["Name","Weight"];

// Define a new object that holds your result
const result = {};

// Loop trought every key using `.forEach` (can also be done using while/for loop)
// ... and writing a new property to result (using e as key and data[e] as value)
arrData.forEach(e => result[e] = data[e]);
console.log(result)
```

---

Or even as one-liner:

```js
const data = {
  Name: "Apple",
  Weight: 5,
  Address: "Somewhere",
  Contact: 777666,
  X: 908,
  Y: 562,
}

const result = (o={},["Name", "Weight"].map((e, v)=>o[e]=data[e] ), o);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = {
  Name: "Apple",
  Weight: 5,
  Address: "Somewhere",
  Contact: 777666,
  X: 908,
  Y: 562,
}
const arrData = ["Name", "Weight"];
let newData = {};
arrData.forEach(x => {
  newData[x] = data[x]
})

console.log(newData);
```